# Проброс VPN клиентов в сеть

Tags: centos, vpn, mikrotik

[image: схема]

Доброго времени суток. Такая проблема - нужно организовать vpn канал между удаленным сервером (CentOS) и офисом. То есть, клиент должен заходить по внешнему IP сервера и по vpn попадать во внутреннюю сеть офиса.

Тунель поднят по PPTP, все хорошо, роутер (микротик) и vpn сервер видят друг друга. В iptables добавлены правила нат, например я 80 порт с 89.40.30.1 пробрасываю на морду микротика (192.168.40.2), все работает, из локалки интернет по vpn работает.

Однако дальше микротика ничего не видно (хотя сам микротик видит локалку)
Микротик создает сам динамический маршрут до vpn-сервера, и видит его.

Конфиг iptables:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.10
COMMIT
#
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Подскажите, куда копать - это iptables надо настраивать, или в микротике беда?

Comment: Статический маршрут на Centos добавлен: 192.168.0.1/24 via 192.168.40.2 dev ppp0

Comment: 1) Убедитесь, что центось может пинговать машины в локалке; 2) Убедитесь, что у микротика есть маршрут до сети, из которой выдаются адреса VPN-клиентам; 3) убедитесь, что на центоси вообще включен форвардинг (sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward); 4) Если ничто не помогает, посмотрите на центоси tcpdump-ом на ppp-интерфейсах клиентов и туннеля.

Answer (score 2):

Микротик не имеет понятия об IP клиентов. Добавьте маршрут на микротике до клиентов через VPN.

Или включите маскарад  `-t nat -A POSTROUTING -s CLIENT_POOL -j MASQUERADE`

Answer (score 0):

Включить proxy-arp в bridge и в routse у казать локальную сеть к ней привязать VPN туннель!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Проксиарп не достаточно просто включить